# How to use hasAspectEvaluator in Alfresco share extension module

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am trying to hide some of the components which appears in document details page of alfresco share based on some aspect.
I am not able to use hasAspectEvaluator for that could anybody please explain how to use that?

Comment: Could you clarify why you can't use `hasAspectEvaluator`?

Comment: the reason is this evaluator is for Document Library where as what I want is evaluator for the extension module and as I have just checked with Dave it there is no OOTB hasAspectEvaluator for extension module I have to crate my own.Let me know if you have done something similar.

Comment: can you explain extension module? if you are talking about hiding actions in document detail page, yes its possible